# python pip package install fails , dllwrap error after 'fixing': "unable to find vcvarsall.bat"

Tags: python, mingw, distutils, python-2.6

I can't find this in the archives. Is there something not right with mingw/msys?
[I need to get vcvarsall.bat fixed, so I can install other packages.]

Failure to install python package 'twisted' using pip.exe.

I have python2.6 and mingw/msys installed.
%PATH% includes `C:\MinGW\` and `C:\MinGW\mingw32\bin`

first: `pip.exe install twisted` fails by saying `error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat`
I create file `G:\Programs (x86)\Python 2.6\Lib\distutils\distutils.cfg`, which contains:

```
[build]
compiler=mingw32
```

Now the error I get is:

```
g:\Programs (x86)\Python 2.6>python Scripts\pip-script.py install twisted
Downloading/unpacking twisted
  Running setup.py egg_info for package twisted
Downloading/unpacking zope.interface (from twisted)
  Running setup.py egg_info for package zope.interface
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools in g:\progr
ams (x86)\python 2.6\lib\site-packages (from zope.interface->twisted)
Installing collected packages: twisted, zope.interface
  Running setup.py install for twisted
    C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall "-Ig:\Programs (x86)\Python
2.6\include" "-Ig:\Programs (x86)\Python 2.6\PC" -c conftest.c -o conftest.o
    conftest.c:1:21: fatal error: rpc/rpc.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall "-Ig:\Programs (x86)\Python
2.6\include" "-Ig:\Programs (x86)\Python 2.6\PC" -c conftest.c -o conftest.o
    conftest.c:1:23: fatal error: sys/epoll.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    building 'twisted.protocols._c_urlarg' extension
    C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall -DWIN32=1 "-Ig:\Programs (x8
6)\Python 2.6\include" "-Ig:\Programs (x86)\Python 2.6\PC" -c twisted/protocols/
_c_urlarg.c -o build\temp.win32-2.6\Release\twisted\protocols\_c_urlarg.o
    twisted/protocols/_c_urlarg.c: In function 'unquote':
    twisted/protocols/_c_urlarg.c:41:50: warning: 'tmp' may be used uninitialize
d in this function
    C:\MinGW\bin\dllwrap.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -static --output-lib build\temp.w
in32-2.6\Release\twisted\protocols\lib_c_urlarg.a --def build\temp.win32-2.6\Rel
ease\twisted\protocols\_c_urlarg.def -s build\temp.win32-2.6\Release\twisted\pro
tocols\_c_urlarg.o "-Lg:\Programs (x86)\Python 2.6\libs" "-Lg:\Programs (x86)\Py
thon 2.6\PCbuild" -lpython26 -lmsvcr90 -o build\lib.win32-2.6\twisted\protocols\
_c_urlarg.pyd
    _c_urlarg.exp: file not recognized: File format not recognized
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    dllwrap: gcc exited with status 1
    error: command 'dllwrap' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command "g:\Programs (x86)\Python 2.6\python.exe" -c "i
mport setuptools;__file__='g:\\Programs (x86)\\Python 2.6\\build\\twisted\\setup
.py';execfile(__file__)" install --single-version-externally-managed --record c:
\users\jake\appdata\local\temp\pip-3y_c1e-record\install-record.txt:
    running install

running build

running build_py

running egg_info

writing requirements to Twisted.egg-info\requires.txt

writing Twisted.egg-info\PKG-INFO

writing top-level names to Twisted.egg-info\top_level.txt

writing dependency_links to Twisted.egg-info\dependency_links.txt

reading manifest file 'Twisted.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'

writing manifest file 'Twisted.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'

running build_ext

C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall "-Ig:\Programs (x86)\Python 2.6\
include" "-Ig:\Programs (x86)\Python 2.6\PC" -c conftest.c -o conftest.o

conftest.c:1:21: fatal error: rpc/rpc.h: No such file or directory

compilation terminated.

C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall "-Ig:\Programs (x86)\Python 2.6\
include" "-Ig:\Programs (x86)\Python 2.6\PC" -c conftest.c -o conftest.o

conftest.c:1:23: fatal error: sys/epoll.h: No such file or directory

compilation terminated.

building 'twisted.protocols._c_urlarg' extension

C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall -DWIN32=1 "-Ig:\Programs (x86)\P
ython 2.6\include" "-Ig:\Programs (x86)\Python 2.6\PC" -c twisted/protocols/_c_u
rlarg.c -o build\temp.win32-2.6\Release\twisted\protocols\_c_urlarg.o

twisted/protocols/_c_urlarg.c: In function 'unquote':

twisted/protocols/_c_urlarg.c:41:50: warning: 'tmp' may be used uninitialized in
 this function

writing build\temp.win32-2.6\Release\twisted\protocols\_c_urlarg.def

C:\MinGW\bin\dllwrap.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -static --output-lib build\temp.win32
-2.6\Release\twisted\protocols\lib_c_urlarg.a --def build\temp.win32-2.6\Release
\twisted\protocols\_c_urlarg.def -s build\temp.win32-2.6\Release\twisted\protoco
ls\_c_urlarg.o "-Lg:\Programs (x86)\Python 2.6\libs" "-Lg:\Programs (x86)\Python
 2.6\PCbuild" -lpython26 -lmsvcr90 -o build\lib.win32-2.6\twisted\protocols\_c_u
rlarg.pyd

_c_urlarg.exp: file not recognized: File format not recognized

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

dllwrap: gcc exited with status 1

warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

error: command 'dllwrap' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command "g:\Programs (x86)\Python 2.6\python.exe" -c "import setuptools;__file__
='g:\\Programs (x86)\\Python 2.6\\build\\twisted\\setup.py';execfile(__file__)"
install --single-version-externally-managed --record c:\users\jake\appdata\local
\temp\pip-3y_c1e-record\install-record.txt failed with error code 1
Storing complete log in C:\Users\jake\AppData\Roaming\pip\pip.log
```

Comment: I realize this is an old post, but I still ran into this problem trying to install Twisted with Python2.7 and pip. I used easy_install instead and it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely a bug with Python. See http://bugs.python.org/issue2698

Meanwhile, you could install [ActivePython](http://activestate.com/activepython/downloads) and [install Twisted](http://code.activestate.com/pypm/twisted/) via PyPM (no compilers needed).

Alternatively, you can use [the official binary](http://pypi.python.org/packages/2.6/T/Twisted/Twisted-10.2.0.winxp32-py2.6.msi#md5=ded94c0e8d460daf3631378bb58331c5) ... though I recommend the aforementioned solution as you can easily 'upgrade' to newer versions of Twisted in future.

Answer (score 3):

The question: why does dllwrap give this error within pip?

```
_foo.exp: file not recognized: File format not recognized
```

Short answer: check your PATH. MinGW\bin needs to be near the start of it.

Long answer: For a while I was using a work around. I grabbed the dllwrap command from the pip.log and executed it directly. That built the .pyd and enabled pip install to finish off the job.

I passed the --verbose flag into these two different ways of calling dllwrap. Under pip this was being done.

```
dlltool: Opened temporary file: dumlc.s
dlltool: run: as   -o _bcrypt.exp dumlc.s
dlltool: Generated exports file
```

Calling dllwrap from the command line gave this.

```
C:\MinGW\bin\dlltool: Opened temporary file: demmc.s
C:\MinGW\bin\dlltool: run: C:\MinGW\bin\as   -o _bcrypt.exp demmc.s
C:\MinGW\bin\dlltool: Generated exports file
```

My computer is running Windows 7 64-bit but with 32-bit Python 2.7. It is new but seems to have the AMD APP SDK pre-installed. That has an as.exe which defaults to 64-bit output.

My fix was to edit the PATH so that C:\MinGW\bin is ahead of C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64

This problem could be fixed more robustly in the Python code though I have not pinned down where in virtualenv, pip or distutils that should be done.

There are two other things needed to build extensions using MinGW which I'll repeat here briefly.

### Configure distutils to use the MinGW compiler

This can be done in a variety of files or command line switches. I opted for a file in my home directory.

```
$ cat ~/pydistutils.cfg
[build]
compiler = mingw32
```

### Patch distutils to eliminate the -mno-cygwin switch

As admininistrator edit Lib/distutils/cygwinccompiler.py. Delete the four -mno-cygwin options.

```
s/ -mno-cygwin//
```

-mno-cygwin has been deprecated in gcc for a while and is now an error.

See http://bugs.python.org/issue12641

Comment: The official fix removing `-mnocygwin` has been released in Python 2.7.6 and 3.3.3.

Comment: This is the correct answer, editing the PATH and then rebooting the computer has fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, I have installed Visual Studio 2008 (vcsetup.exe) to go around this problem.

updated link:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15336

If using Python 3.3 you can use Visual Studio 2010

Comment: it has the Windows package needed.  I wasn't sure which package it was so it was easier just to install the whole thing.

Comment: The link isn't working. Seems like Microsoft does not support VS2008 any longer.