# gcc compilation error from python

Tags: python, gcc, cygwin

I know that there are lots of threads on gcc, particularly "command gcc failed with exit status 1", and I've looked at them all and still have not been able to fix this.  I only would use gcc or mingw32 for python-related tasks, such as using Cython or other packages that might involve compilation.  However, it never seems to work.

I have a PC with Windows 7 Home edition.  I've installed cygwin on it with mingw32, and I also have Visual Studio 11 Beta installed, and I'm happy to uninstall/reinstall anything to get this to work.

Cython compilations always fail with

```
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

But even trying to install many python packages using pip fails with a similar error.  For example, I'm trying to install a package called "xhtml2pdf."  After running "pip install xhtml2pdf" in the command prompt, I get the following error:

```
copying src\reportlab\lib\hyphen.mashed -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\lib

running build_ext

building '_rl_accel' extension

C:\mingw\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Pytho
n27\PC -c "C:\Users\JJ\Documents\Coding Fun\build\reportlab\src\rl_addons\rl_acc
el\_rl_accel.c" -o "c:\users\jj\documents\coding fun\build\reportlab\src\rl_addo
ns\rl_accel\_rl_accel.o"

cc1.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-mno-cygwin'

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Running the same command from cygwin yields a different error:

```
copying src\reportlab\lib\hyphen.mashed -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\lib

running build_ext

building '_rl_accel' extension

gcc -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC -c C:\cygwin\home\JJ\build\reportlab\src\rl_addons\rl_accel\_rl_accel.c -o c:\cygwin\home\jj\build\reportlab\src\rl_addons\rl_accel\_rl_accel.o

error: command 'gcc' failed: No such file or directory

----------------------------------------
Command C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools;__file__='C:\\cygwin\\home\\JJ\\build\\reportlab\\setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record c:\users\jj\appdata\local\temp\pip-aohmse-record\install-record.txt failed with error code 1 in C:\cygwin\home\JJ\build\reportlab
Storing complete log in C:\Users\JJ\AppData\Roaming\pip\pip.log


----------------------------------------
Command C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools;__file__='C:\\Users\\JJ\\Do
cuments\\Coding Fun\\build\\reportlab\\setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).rea
d().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-external
ly-managed --record c:\users\jj\appdata\local\temp\pip-r8_mri-record\install-rec
ord.txt failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\JJ\Documents\Coding Fun\build\repor
tlab
Storing complete log in C:\Users\JJ\AppData\Roaming\pip\pip.log
```

I'm very new to compilation in general, having worked only with interpreted languages, so I've been frustratingly unable to figure out how to fix this myself.  Any help would be appreciated in getting this package installed.

EDIT: I have previously followed advice like trying to remove all references to "-mno-cygwin" in distutils and creating a distutils.cfg file, but to no avail.

UPDATE: After reinstalling cygwin and also downgrading my installations of gcc and g++ to v3, I get another, but different, error:

```
copying src\reportlab\lib\PyFontify.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\lib

copying src\reportlab\lib\pygments2xpre.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\lib

copying src\reportlab\lib\randomtext.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\lib

copying src\reportlab\lib\rltempfile.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\lib

copying src\reportlab\lib\rparsexml.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\lib

copying src\reportlab\lib\sequencer.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\lib

copying src\reportlab\lib\set_ops.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\lib

copying src\reportlab\lib\styles.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\lib

copying src\reportlab\lib\testutils.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\lib

copying src\reportlab\lib\textsplit.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\lib

copying src\reportlab\lib\units.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\lib

copying src\reportlab\lib\utils.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\lib

copying src\reportlab\lib\validators.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\lib

copying src\reportlab\lib\xmllib.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\lib

copying src\reportlab\lib\yaml.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\lib

copying src\reportlab\lib\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\lib

copying src\reportlab\pdfbase\cidfonts.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\pdfba
se

copying src\reportlab\pdfbase\pdfdoc.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\pdfbase


copying src\reportlab\pdfbase\pdfform.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\pdfbas
e

copying src\reportlab\pdfbase\pdfmetrics.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\pdf
base

copying src\reportlab\pdfbase\pdfpattern.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\pdf
base

copying src\reportlab\pdfbase\pdfutils.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\pdfba
se

copying src\reportlab\pdfbase\rl_codecs.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\pdfb
ase

copying src\reportlab\pdfbase\ttfonts.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\pdfbas
e

copying src\reportlab\pdfbase\_can_cmap_data.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab
\pdfbase

copying src\reportlab\pdfbase\_cidfontdata.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\p
dfbase

copying src\reportlab\pdfbase\_fontdata.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\pdfb
ase

copying src\reportlab\pdfbase\_fontdata_enc_macexpert.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\
reportlab\pdfbase

copying src\reportlab\pdfbase\_fontdata_enc_macroman.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\r
eportlab\pdfbase

copying src\reportlab\pdfbase\_fontdata_enc_pdfdoc.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\rep
ortlab\pdfbase

copying src\reportlab\pdfbase\_fontdata_enc_standard.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\r
eportlab\pdfbase

copying src\reportlab\pdfbase\_fontdata_enc_symbol.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\rep
ortlab\pdfbase

copying src\reportlab\pdfbase\_fontdata_enc_winansi.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\re
portlab\pdfbase

copying src\reportlab\pdfbase\_fontdata_enc_zapfdingbats.py -> build\lib.win32-2
.7\reportlab\pdfbase

copying src\reportlab\pdfbase\_fontdata_widths_courier.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7
\reportlab\pdfbase

copying src\reportlab\pdfbase\_fontdata_widths_courierbold.py -> build\lib.win32
-2.7\reportlab\pdfbase

copying src\reportlab\pdfbase\_fontdata_widths_courierboldoblique.py -> build\li
b.win32-2.7\reportlab\pdfbase

copying src\reportlab\pdfbase\_fontdata_widths_courieroblique.py -> build\lib.wi
n32-2.7\reportlab\pdfbase

copying src\reportlab\pdfbase\_fontdata_widths_helvetica.py -> build\lib.win32-2
.7\reportlab\pdfbase

copying src\reportlab\pdfbase\_fontdata_widths_helveticabold.py -> build\lib.win
32-2.7\reportlab\pdfbase

copying src\reportlab\pdfbase\_fontdata_widths_helveticaboldoblique.py -> build\
lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\pdfbase

copying src\reportlab\pdfbase\_fontdata_widths_helveticaoblique.py -> build\lib.
win32-2.7\reportlab\pdfbase

copying src\reportlab\pdfbase\_fontdata_widths_symbol.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\
reportlab\pdfbase

copying src\reportlab\pdfbase\_fontdata_widths_timesbold.py -> build\lib.win32-2
.7\reportlab\pdfbase

copying src\reportlab\pdfbase\_fontdata_widths_timesbolditalic.py -> build\lib.w
in32-2.7\reportlab\pdfbase

copying src\reportlab\pdfbase\_fontdata_widths_timesitalic.py -> build\lib.win32
-2.7\reportlab\pdfbase

copying src\reportlab\pdfbase\_fontdata_widths_timesroman.py -> build\lib.win32-
2.7\reportlab\pdfbase

copying src\reportlab\pdfbase\_fontdata_widths_zapfdingbats.py -> build\lib.win3
2-2.7\reportlab\pdfbase

copying src\reportlab\pdfbase\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\pdfba
se

copying src\reportlab\pdfgen\canvas.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\pdfgen

copying src\reportlab\pdfgen\pathobject.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\pdfg
en

copying src\reportlab\pdfgen\pdfgeom.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\pdfgen

copying src\reportlab\pdfgen\pdfimages.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\pdfge
n

copying src\reportlab\pdfgen\pycanvas.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\pdfgen


copying src\reportlab\pdfgen\textobject.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\pdfg
en

copying src\reportlab\pdfgen\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\pdfgen


copying src\reportlab\platypus\doctemplate.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\p
latypus

copying src\reportlab\platypus\figures.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\platy
pus

copying src\reportlab\platypus\flowables.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\pla
typus

copying src\reportlab\platypus\frames.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\platyp
us

copying src\reportlab\platypus\para.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\platypus


copying src\reportlab\platypus\paragraph.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\pla
typus

copying src\reportlab\platypus\paraparser.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\pl
atypus

copying src\reportlab\platypus\tableofcontents.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportl
ab\platypus

copying src\reportlab\platypus\tables.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\platyp
us

copying src\reportlab\platypus\xpreformatted.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab
\platypus

copying src\reportlab\platypus\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\plat
ypus

copying src\reportlab\fonts\00readme.txt -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\fonts

copying src\reportlab\fonts\bitstream-vera-license.txt -> build\lib.win32-2.7\re
portlab\fonts

copying src\reportlab\fonts\DarkGarden-copying-gpl.txt -> build\lib.win32-2.7\re
portlab\fonts

copying src\reportlab\fonts\DarkGarden-copying.txt -> build\lib.win32-2.7\report
lab\fonts

copying src\reportlab\fonts\DarkGarden-readme.txt -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportl
ab\fonts

copying src\reportlab\fonts\DarkGarden.sfd -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\font
s

copying src\reportlab\fonts\DarkGardenMK.afm -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\fo
nts

copying src\reportlab\fonts\DarkGardenMK.pfb -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\fo
nts

copying src\reportlab\fonts\Vera.ttf -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\fonts

copying src\reportlab\fonts\VeraBd.ttf -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\fonts

copying src\reportlab\fonts\VeraBI.ttf -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\fonts

copying src\reportlab\fonts\VeraIt.ttf -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\fonts

copying src\reportlab\fonts\_abi____.pfb -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\fonts

copying src\reportlab\fonts\_ab_____.pfb -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\fonts

copying src\reportlab\fonts\_ai_____.pfb -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\fonts

copying src\reportlab\fonts\_a______.pfb -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\fonts

copying src\reportlab\fonts\cobo____.pfb -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\fonts

copying src\reportlab\fonts\cob_____.pfb -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\fonts

copying src\reportlab\fonts\com_____.pfb -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\fonts

copying src\reportlab\fonts\coo_____.pfb -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\fonts

copying src\reportlab\fonts\_ebi____.pfb -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\fonts

copying src\reportlab\fonts\_eb_____.pfb -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\fonts

copying src\reportlab\fonts\_ei_____.pfb -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\fonts

copying src\reportlab\fonts\_er_____.pfb -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\fonts

copying src\reportlab\fonts\Sy______.pfb -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\fonts

copying src\reportlab\fonts\Zd______.pfb -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\fonts

copying src\reportlab\fonts\Zx______.pfb -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\fonts

copying src\reportlab\fonts\Zy______.pfb -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\fonts

copying src\reportlab\lib\hyphen.mashed -> build\lib.win32-2.7\reportlab\lib

running build_ext

building '_rl_accel' extension

C:\mingw\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Pytho
n27\PC -c C:\Users\JJ\Documents\build\reportlab\src\rl_addons\rl_accel\_rl_accel
.c -o c:\users\jj\documents\build\reportlab\src\rl_addons\rl_accel\_rl_accel.o

C:\Users\JJ\Documents\build\reportlab\src\rl_addons\rl_accel\_rl_accel.c: In fun
ction `hex32':

C:\Users\JJ\Documents\build\reportlab\src\rl_addons\rl_accel\_rl_accel.c:491: wa
rning: unsigned int format, long unsigned int arg (arg 3)

C:\Users\JJ\Documents\build\reportlab\src\rl_addons\rl_accel\_rl_accel.c: In fun
ction `_instanceStringWidthU':

C:\Users\JJ\Documents\build\reportlab\src\rl_addons\rl_accel\_rl_accel.c:741: wa
rning: 'L' might be used uninitialized in this function

C:\Users\JJ\Documents\build\reportlab\src\rl_addons\rl_accel\_rl_accel.c:741: wa
rning: 't' might be used uninitialized in this function

C:\Users\JJ\Documents\build\reportlab\src\rl_addons\rl_accel\_rl_accel.c:741: wa
rning: 'f' might be used uninitialized in this function

writing c:\users\jj\documents\build\reportlab\src\rl_addons\rl_accel\_rl_accel.d
ef

C:\mingw\bin\dllwrap.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -static --output-lib c:\users\jj\docu
ments\build\reportlab\src\rl_addons\rl_accel\lib_rl_accel.a --def c:\users\jj\do
cuments\build\reportlab\src\rl_addons\rl_accel\_rl_accel.def -s c:\users\jj\docu
ments\build\reportlab\src\rl_addons\rl_accel\_rl_accel.o -LC:\Python27\libs -LC:
\Python27\PCbuild -lpython27 -lmsvcr90 -o build\lib.win32-2.7\_rl_accel.pyd

_rl_accel.exp: file not recognized: File format not recognized

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

dllwrap: gcc exited with status 1

error: command 'dllwrap' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: It looks like (in the case of your cygwin attempt), A gcc binary is not in your path. I don't have a windows machine to hand to help you out in solving this, but try rerunning the cygwin installer and ensuring gcc is being installed. If it is, add it to your path (In Windows I think you do this from 'System' in the Control Panel, if memory serves me correctly.)

Comment: Thanks, I had realized that already.  I'll give reinstalling cygwin a shot, though I'm really looking to be able to run pip from command prompt.  I do already have "C:\mingw\bin" in my system path though.

Comment: i'm a little confused.  i thought mingw and cygwin were different things.  i thought cygwin had its own gcc, that was nothing to do with mingw.  and that would explain why cygwin is giving an error even though mingw is present.  in the cygwin installer you need to dig around to find the gcc-related option and enable it, i think.  i have never used mingw, so can't comment on the first error, but majackson seems right about the second.  or perhaps cygwin and mingw have merged or something?

Comment: No, you're probably right; I have no idea--hence my question.  I didn't realize that cygwin and mingw have different gccs.  How would you go about fixing it then?

Comment: By rerunning setup.exe and ensuring that gcc is installed from within Cygwin.  It's not something that gets installed by default.

Comment: You should open another question, not tack it into this one, with the second issue. Also, please post how you fixed this and accept your answer when allowed.

Comment: I will, but I believe that this is still the same issue, hence (a) the update rather than a new posting, and (b) why I have not marked it solved.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So, after a while, I stumbled across a post that so far has worked for me.

http://www.develer.com/oss/GccWinBinaries

This site provides an unofficial MinGW GCC binary (not supported/endorsed by MinGW) that is meant to integrate perfectly with Python, down to the automatic updating of paths.  I installed it and bam, `pip install cython` just started working.

Hope this helps more of you out there with this gcc problem.

Comment: GccWinBinaries doesn't support [64-bit Windows](https://github.com/develersrl/gccwinbinaries/issues/2#issuecomment-26124359).

Comment: GccWinBinaries DOES support 64-bit Windows, just not 64-bit Python. But with a 32-bit Python it works flawlessly on my Windows 7 64-bit machine. It won't however compile Cython extensions.

Answer (score 2):

I've just answered the same question: why does dllwrap give this error within pip?

```
_foo.exp: file not recognized: File format not recognized
```

Short answer: check your PATH. MinGW\bin needs to be near the start of it.

Long answer: see [python pip package install fails , dllwrap error after 'fixing': "unable to find vcvarsall.bat"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439160)

Comment: Indeed, changing the system PATH and rebooting fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue in cygwin until I realised that the gcc-g++ package needed to be installed also. Now that I have both gcc-core and gcc-g++ installed, `pip install pandas` works like a charm.