# Compiling Python Imaging Library with MinGW

Tags: mingw, python-imaging-library, python-c-api

I'm trying to compile Python Imaging Library on **Windows 7 64-bit** by running

```
pip install pil
```

I've set my compiler to MinGW. It looks like it's going fine until it's time to compile _imaging.c. It fails on this monster gcc call:

```
 C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -shared -s build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\_imaging.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\decode.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\encode.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\map.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\display.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\outline.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\path.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libimaging\access.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libimaging\antialias.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libimaging\bands.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libimaging\bitdecode.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libimaging\blend.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libimaging\chops.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libimaging\convert.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libimaging\convertycbcr.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libimaging\copy.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libimaging\crc32.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libimaging\crop.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libimaging\dib.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libimaging\draw.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libimaging\effects.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libimaging\epsencode.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libimaging\file.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libimaging\fill.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libimaging\filter.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libimaging\flidecode.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libimaging\geometry.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libimaging\getbbox.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libimaging\gifdecode.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libimaging\gifencode.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libimaging\hexdecode.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libimaging\histo.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libimaging\jpegdecode.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libimaging\jpegencode.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libimaging\lzwdecode.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libimaging\matrix.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libimaging\modefilter.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libimaging\mspdecode.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libimaging\negative.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libimaging\offset.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libimaging\pack.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libimaging\packdecode.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libimaging\palette.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libimaging\paste.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libimaging\quant.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libimaging\quanthash.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libimaging\quantheap.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libimaging\pcddecode.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libimaging\pcxdecode.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libimaging\pcxencode.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libimaging\point.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libimaging\rankfilter.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libimaging\rawdecode.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libimaging\rawencode.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libimaging\storage.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libimaging\sunrledecode.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libimaging\tgarledecode.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libimaging\unpack.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libimaging\unpackycc.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libimaging\unsharpmask.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libimaging\xbmdecode.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libimaging\xbmencode.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libimaging\zipdecode.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\libimaging\zipencode.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\_imaging.def -LC:\Python27\lib -LC:\Python27\libs -LC:\Python27\PCbuild\amd64 -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lpython27 -lmsvcr90 -o build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\_imaging.pyd
```

The error from this call starts off like:

```
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\_imaging.o:_imaging.c:(.text+0x70): undefined reference to `__imp__PyFloat_Type'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\_imaging.o:_imaging.c:(.text+0x78): undefined reference to `__imp__PyFloat_Type'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\_imaging.o:_imaging.c:(.text+0x85): undefined reference to `__imp__PyType_IsSubtype'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\_imaging.o:_imaging.c:(.text+0xc9): undefined reference to `__imp__PyFloat_Type'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\_imaging.o:_imaging.c:(.text+0xd1): undefined reference to `__imp__PyFloat_Type'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\_imaging.o:_imaging.c:(.text+0xde): undefined reference to `__imp__PyType_IsSubtype'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\_imaging.o:_imaging.c:(.text+0x113): undefined reference to `__imp__PyExc_TypeError'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\_imaging.o:_imaging.c:(.text+0x11e): undefined reference to `__imp__PyErr_SetString'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\_imaging.o:_imaging.c:(.text+0x132): undefined reference to `__imp__PyExc_TypeError'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\_imaging.o:_imaging.c:(.text+0x13d): undefined reference to `__imp__PyErr_SetString'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\_imaging.o:_imaging.c:(.text+0x194): undefined reference to `__imp__PyInt_AsLong'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\_imaging.o:_imaging.c:(.text+0x1a3): undefined reference to `__imp__PyErr_Occurred'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\_imaging.o:_imaging.c:(.text+0x23e): undefined reference to `__imp__PyArg_ParseTuple'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\_imaging.o:_imaging.c:(.text+0x285): undefined reference to `__imp__PyArg_ParseTuple'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\_imaging.o:_imaging.c:(.text+0x316): undefined reference to `__imp__PyInt_AsLong'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\_imaging.o:_imaging.c:(.text+0x325): undefined reference to `__imp__PyErr_Occurred'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\_imaging.o:_imaging.c:(.text+0x341): undefined reference to `__imp__PyFloat_AsDouble'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\_imaging.o:_imaging.c:(.text+0x35f): undefined reference to `__imp__PyErr_Occurred'
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\_imaging.o:_imaging.c:(.text+0x393): undefined reference to `__imp__PyInt_AsLong'
```

I assume these weird undefined things are part of the Python C API. So why would I get these errors if the gcc call is including -lpython27?

Comment: What OS are you using?  There are known issues with this in Windows.

Comment: Sorry, added my OS. It's Windows 7 64-bit

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of known problems with compiling in Windows as part of Python package installation.  I'd recommend that you go with the [Unofficial Windows Binaries](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) that have worked for me in the past.

You could install PIL with:

```
easy_install http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/xos8d83j/PIL-fork-1.1.7.win-amd64-py2.7.exe
```

Comment: Thanks for the work around, but I'd still like to know why the compiler does not succeed. Wouldn't that qualify as a compiler bug?

Comment: A compiler bug, maybe, but it's definitely more complicated and there are a lot of moving parts with getting the compilers working on Windows.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10281102/gcc-compilation-error-from-python) and also look up other Windows gcc compilation issues; you'll find lots of reports of it.  As for why it doesn't work, I don't exactly know.  I know it's an open issue though--I forget whether with Python or with GCC or Mingw.