# Trying to Build a Cython File - Getting Error (Python 2.7, Windows 7 64-bit)

Tags: python, cython

I'm using Python 2.7 in Windows Powershell (I set the environment so I can use Python).

I have Cython installed (using the Windows installer).

I'm trying to follow the tutorial on the Cython website by making a simple "Hello World" extension, but when I try to build the extension I get this error:

```
dllwrap: gcc exited with status 1
error: command 'dllwrap' failed with exit status 1
```

How do I resolve this so that I may optimize my python code by C extensions?

Comment: Is there any relevant error data above the `gcc exited with status 1` line? The fact that it exited doesn't provide enough information.

Comment: Hello, here is the rest of the code:

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/5439160/1947535

Answer (score 0):

Here is the rest of the error code:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\Pinky> cd Programming
PS C:\Users\Pinky\Programming> python setup.py build_ext --inplace
running build_ext
skipping 'helloworld.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
building 'helloworld' extension
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC -c helloworld.c -o build\temp.win32-2.7\Relea
se\helloworld.o
writing build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\helloworld.def
C:\MinGW\bin\dllwrap.exe -mdll -static --output-lib build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\libhelloworld.a --def build\temp.win32-
2.7\Release\helloworld.def -s build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\helloworld.o -LC:\Python27\libs -LC:\Python27\PCbuild -lpytho
n27 -lmsvcr90 -o C:\Users\Pinky\Programming\helloworld.pyd
helloworld.exp: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
dllwrap: gcc exited with status 1
error: command 'dllwrap' failed with exit status 1
PS C:\Users\Pinky\Programming>
```

Comment: Setup.py is the file that is supposed to apply the C code (or something) and turn my python file into a Cython extension.  It comes from this tutorial:  http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/tutorial.html

Comment: Its still not working.  I put Ming/bin near the start of my environment path, deleted -mno-cygwin from the compiler.py.. It still gives me the error.

Comment: I managed to solve it.  I forgot to put the "C:\" in the MingGW and also you need to type this into powershell to set its environment: $env:path = "C:\MinGW\bin;"+$env:path#

Comment: It would be worth editing your answer to include full details of how you solved your own issue. Glad to hear you got it sorted.